# Magento2 people on same network logged into each others account with form keys disabled

Tags: magento2, forms, form-key

With  magento config:set admin/security/use_form_key 0

People say that sometimes they are logged into each others accounts.  I'm not sure how this is possible since they never log into each others computers and thus wouldn't even have the session cookie.  We go through cloudflare, but that should make no difference at all.  We use redis but that too should make no difference at all.  It does have us a bit worried though.

Having form keys on is a huge pain as we can't copy an admin url and give it to someone else.  It's really upsetting it does this with form keys off.

Comment: Have you got examples of the type of URLs that you share?

Comment: https://domain.com/admin_zsdf12/catalog/product/edit/id/125408/key/0224f67823409436082019312781e4b3e0c3eafzc9f053af0f7dd3d33d10e0e7/

as an example.  "hey can you take a look at this product?"  "sure link me the product in the backend!" ya that doesn't work with m2 keys turned on it just redirects you to the main page.